# MS Project Change Working Time - Roster

Tags: ms-project, planning

How can I change the working time to 2 weeks ( working - 14 days) and 1 week (not working - 7 days)? Is this able to be automatically populated?

Answer (score 1):

1. "Create a New Calendar" by copying the existing "Standard" (5dx8h) calendar.  I would name the new calendar something like "7dx8h:2w+1w."
2. Reset the default Work Weeks of the new calendar to include Sunday and Saturday as normal workdays.[image: WorkWeek Mod]
3. On the Exceptions tab, add a new "Rest Week" exception.  In the Details for "Rest Week", specify the exception as Nonworking, with Weekly recurrence pattern, recurring every 3 weeks on (check all 7 weekdays).  Set the Range of recurrence however you need. [image]